# Highlight word in webpage without .innerhtml

Tags: javascript

I want to highlight a word in a page without involving the `document.body.innerHTML` as this totally alters the functionality of the page.

Is there any other way to do it?

Right now I am using this code to highlight

```js
document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(/TEST/g, function(m){
    return '<span style="background-color:YELLOW">'+m+'</span>'
}
```

Thank you

Comment: How are you currently highlighting the word? Please add your code so we can help.

Comment: @cSharp, I have edited my question and have added the code I am currently using.

Comment: Are you scanning the entire `body.innerHTML` and replacing every `TEST` with yellow `+TEST+`?

Comment: @cSharp, Yes. I need to search the entire webpage for a text and highlight it if found.

Comment: Do you get this webpage from somewhere else, and/or you cannot change it?

Comment: @cSharp, This is not my webpage, I cant edit it, It is a dynamic webpage, I need to extract some defined texts out of it. So, I am trying to highlight those texts for my need.

Comment: Afaik you cannot change the value throughout without replacing it. You can prepend (add at the beginning) or append (add at the end). But if things need to be changed in between the content, your only option is to replace. Another option would be not to touch the page content at all and just use a browser addon like "Highlight This!" to highlight words on a page. But that would only be helpful if this is just for personal use.

Comment: @cSharp, I have tried Highlight this . It also changes the page layout in that specific page I am trying. Can u please give a code to prepend it, in place of highlighting it. I only need it for quick identification of texts in the webpage.

Comment: Have you considered using `window.find`?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find

Comment: "as this totally alters the functionality of the page." Please elaborate on this. We cannot answer your question without knowing the exact boundaries of what is acceptable when making changes to the DOM.

Comment: Can't you just match the DOM-elements with the relevant content and change their styling?

Comment: @RuudHelderman, Its a reporting website . In that website, when I hightlight the word "Age" and enter the value as 10 years, the word gets highlighted and saved for that webpage.

Comment: @VickyLahkar Apologies, I should clarify my comment. Your original question does not explain in what way the manipulation of `document.body.innerHTML` disrupts the original webpage. "Totally alters the functionality of the page" is too vague for me. I can imagine though, that rebuilding the _entire_ DOM can have an impact on dynamic parts of the page (e.g. inline JavaScript). Have you tried modifying the `innerHTML` of a more confined part of the webpage (e.g. a single paragraph)? What happened? If possible, please supply a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I would suggest to retrieve the DOM elements with the relevant content, get the content, and finally surround it with a styled `span` element.

```js
const $matchedElements = document.querySelectorAll("p");

$matchedElements.forEach(($element) => {
  if ($element.innerHTML.match("SampleCollected")) {
    const $mySpan = document.createElement("span");
    $mySpan.style = "background-color:yellow";
    $mySpan.innerHTML = $element.innerHTML;

    $element.innerHTML = ""
    $element.appendChild($mySpan)
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>
      SampleCollected
    </p>
    <p>
      SampleNotCollected
    </p>
    <p>
      SampleCollected
    </p>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, But this is not working in the website strangely.

Comment: Probably because the CSS selector does not match. Could you also provide the HTML code of the web page?

Comment: Its a lot of text. Will it be safe to post it here?

Comment: CSS selector for that element is `body > form#form1:nth-child(1) > table.tableborder.w-100p:nth-child(59) > tbody > tr > td#tdspace.tdspace.v-top.w-100p > div.contentdata:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(3) > div#up1 > div#pnlDept > div:nth-child(2) > table#grdresult.gridView.w-100p.m-auto > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.w-15p:nth-child(12)`